# How to inject multiple React components to ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-mvc-4

My company has a fully functioning ASP.NET MVC app (with Razor views).
They want to move to using React on the frontend.

Now I understand how to inject a React app it's just they want to do it bit by bit. Replace couple of components on the page then maybe the whole view and the move to another one.

Normally React creates a bundle that you just import to your index file. But that's just one endpoint. Not sure if this would work in this scenario.